# Django: How do I get an array from a QueryDict in a template?

Tags: django, arrays, templates

I've got the following QueryDict object in my request.session.

```
<QueryDict: {u'category': [u'44', u'46'], u'cityID': [u'null'], u'countryCode': [u''], u'mapCenterLng': [u'2.291300800000009'], u'mapZoom': [u'12'], u'mapCenterLat': [u'47.10983460000001'], u'price_range': [u''], u'textbox': [u'']}>
```

In a template try to get the category array using:

```
{{request.session.lastrequest.category}}
```

but this gives me only the last value of the array.
How can I get the entire array?

Thanks

Jul

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can't. You need to call [`.getlist('category')`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist), but you can't call methods with a parameter in a template.

Comment: Wow, fast reply. I'll find an alternative then. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I needed access to a QueryDict too, so I added a filter and it worked for my needs.

Wherever you registered your app filters:

```
#/templatetags/app_filters.py
from django import template
register = template.Library()

# Calls .getlist() on a querydict
# Use: querydict | get_list {{ querydict|get_list:"itemToGet" }}
@register.filter
def get_list(querydict, itemToGet ):

    return querydict.getlist(itemToGet)
```

In template:

```
{% load app_filters %}

{% for each in form.data|get_list:"itemYouAreInterestedIn" %}
     {{each}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Here is the [reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-template-tags/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `QueryDict`'s method `lists()`:

```
{% for k, v in request.session.lastrequest.lists %}{% if k == 'category' %}{{ v }}{% endif %}{% endfor %}
```

Although you need to loop through the whole dictionary, it will only enter the `if` statement once. `v` is always a list there.